# Do attributive-only adjectives take 的?

Tags: adjectives, morphology

Do attributive-only adjectives like 公共 or 男/女 take 的 at all when modifying a noun?

I realize that they take 的 when in '是—的' construction.  But is it correct to say 公共的建築 or 男的律師.  Or can one only say 公共建築 and 男律師?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do attributive-only adjectives like 公共 or 男/女 take 的 at all when modifying a noun?

They can

Without 的, 男律師 can be a description of a specific male lawyer or male lawyers in general

Example:

- 他的辯護律師團由一名男律師，兩名女律師組成
- 男(性)律師收入高於女(性)律師

男的律師 mainly refers to male lawyers in general

Example:

- 男(性)的律師收入高於女(性)的律師
- 的 would be redundant in 他的辯護律師團由一名男的律師，兩名女的律師組成

So, adding 的 after an attributive-only adjective makes it precisely a 'in general' description

Comment: So it’s like the difference between, ‘male lawyers are taller’ and ‘I know a male lawyer’?  Does this also apply to 公共 or 金/銀?

Comment: yes, 一間公共圖書舘 -->公共的圖書館不像私人的圖書館一般不受政府管制：一把金劍，一把銀刀 --> 金的劍，銀的刀都是富人的武器

Comment: 公共圖書館不像私人圖書館一般不受政府管制 and 金劍，銀刀都是富人的武器 are also valid because attributive-only adjectives can be used for specific or for in- general description.  Adding 的 restrict it to in- general description